# Row organized raster file to Column organized raster file

Tags: python, numpy, gis, xyz

I have a (2x3) raster file with the following values:

```
-5-6
-4-5
-1-2
```

Normally the .xyz GIS file format would be column organised represented by the following numpy array: (coordinates are lower left corner)

```py
col = numpy.array([[0,0,-1],[1,0,-2],[0,1,-3],[1,1,-4],[0,2,-5],[1,2,-6]])
```

Unfortunately I have a row organized structure (from this data comes from https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/).  It can be represented by the following numpy array:

```py
row = numpy.array([[0,0,-1],[0,1,-3],[0,2,-5],[1,0,-2],[1,1,-4],[1,2,-6]])
print (row)
[[ 0  0 -1]
 [ 0  1 -3]
 [ 0  2 -5]
 [ 1  0 -2]
 [ 1  1 -4]
 [ 1  2 -6]]
```

I need to rearrange this row array into a col array. I am currently using this code:

```py
rr = row.reshape(2,3,3)
stack = numpy.column_stack(rr[:,:,:])
new_col =(stack.reshape(-1,3))
print (new_col)

[[ 0  0 -1]
 [ 1  0 -2]
 [ 0  1 -3]
 [ 1  1 -4]
 [ 0  2 -5]
 [ 1  2 -6]]
```

This works but my question: Is this the best way to tackle this array transformation? I have little experience manipulation numpy arrays.
Thanks
Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) method to rearrange the axes.

```
import numpy

col = numpy.array([[0,0,-1],[1,0,-2],[0,1,-3],[1,1,-4],[0,2,-5],[1,2,-6]])
row = numpy.array([[0,0,-1],[0,1,-3],[0,2,-5],[1,0,-2],[1,1,-4],[1,2,-6]])

# New solution
new_col = row.reshape(2,3,3).transpose(1,0,2).reshape(-1,3)

print(numpy.array_equal(col, new_col))
```

It works faster than via using `column_stack` or `hstack`.

Comment: Ok, I will try. That’s what i was aiming for but I could not quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think what your doing is fine, but for readability I would use

`stack = numpy.hstack(rr)`

instead of

`stack = numpy.column_stack(rr[:,:,:])`